# why http directive :Content-Disposition: attachment download forces browser to redirect users back to the page he was coming from

Tags: http, redirect, browser, download, content-disposition

i know this code will force to download the file with the below content , 
but my question is that why using this coding will force the browser to  redirect me back to any page i was coming coming from after the download start ? 
 for example if i was in http://localhost/test.php and i left to test2.php (where content-disposition code exists) , the browser downloads the file that specified in attachment attribute of content-dispotion as mentined below and the window of the browser redirects me back to test.php
and this isn't related to localhost , i tested on live websites 
i read about content disposition in RFC but i missed the luck .

```
<?php 
   $y="testing";
    header('Cache-Control: public');

    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Exported Emails_".date("d-m-Y").".txt");
    echo $y;
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return back"?

Comment: redirects me back to the page where i came from , for example if i was in http://localhost/test.php and i left to test2.php (where content-disposition code exists) , the browser downloads the file and the window of the browser redirect back to test.php

Comment: i added an example to the question so that you can understand it .

Comment: AFAUI, nothing is redirected. You actually don not "leave" the first page at all.

What do you *expect* to happen instead?

Comment: if you are now on facebook and then went to localhost/test.php where the above code located , the browser will download the above data in .txt file and then will redirect automatically to facebook (or whatever you were coming from).

Comment: No, it doesn't "redirect". The browser just happens to *stay* where you came from, as the resource you are navigated to was for download, not display.